# How do I access my Views when using ViewPager/PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Similar question [Access ViewPager views from onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124685/access-viewpager-views-from-oncreate?rq=1)
I created a ViewPager where different layout can moves around. One layout has a button. My question is if a user click on this button, he will move another page. How to achieve it. Here is the viewpager adapter class:

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    private static int[] mLayouts = { R.layout.view_layout1,
            R.layout.view_layout2, R.layout.view_layout3, R.layout.view_layout4 };

    SwipeAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ViewGroup pageView= (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(mLayouts[position],
                container, false);
        container.addView(pageView);
        getItemPosition(pageView);
        return pageView;
    }




    /**
     * @return the mCurrentposition
     */

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLayouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: In the instantiateitem, I want to get the third page button id.

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807262/get-focused-view-from-viewpager

Comment: Post the ViewPager adapter

Comment: hello blackbelt, I add the adapter class. check it, it is simple.